# nodejs server can't access from outside

Tags: node.js, server, centos, centos6

I had been trying all sort of methods, still can't make it work.
Need some help on this.

Running on CentOS release 6.10
Using PM2 to enable the nodejs server.

server.js

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '0.0.0.0';
const port = 3001;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    res.end('This is the Admin Side!\n');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

> curl localhost:3001 is working.

Enable firewall

```
iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:3001 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp spt:3001
```

The port seem open

```
netstat -tnl | grep 3001
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3001                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
```

Comment: what about routing.   first remove firewall rules and everyting.   reach the machine outside with ping.  do a curl outside or nmap or telnet nodeip 3001  to see if you can get access. after this works start closing everything down.

Comment: the machine is also hosting other website using apache.
Just try `service iptables stop` and `chkconfig iptables off` then restart pm2 still unable to access.

Comment: Is this is hosted service which you don't fully control?  might be that these ports are already blocked by the service?

Comment: you are right, I contacted the service to unblock it. Thanks

Comment: your welcome, can you pls accept the answer so my profile gets a boost :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provider not allowing port 3001 by default